# i was trying to map data from api to some jsx element and i keep getting type error

Tags: reactjs

i have data from api to be mapped in to jsx i  have array that have dates stored in it and I want to get patient information in that specific day the information are stored in different array and thus arrys contains objects, in the objects there is a date and the information i want to get on that day
mapping the dates from Dates array to jsx works fine but i couldn't map the other patient information in that day to the jsx
here is my data

```
[
{
    "BloodPressure": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "BloodPressure": "120/80"
        }
    ],
    "Tempreture": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Tempreture": "37"
        }
    ],
    "Weight": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Weight": "50"
        }
    ],
    "Height": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Height": "150"
        }
    ],
    "Pulse": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Pulse": "112"
        }
    ],
    "OxygenSaturation": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "OxygenSaturation": "97"
        }
    ],
    "ChefCompliant": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "ChefCompliant": "sdfghhshsdgh"
        },
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "ChefCompliant": "hod kurtet"
        }
    ],
    "HPI": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "HPI": ""
        },
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "HPI": "mnm"
        }
    ],
    "ProgressNote": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "ProgressNote": ""
        },
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "ProgressNote": "lewtyelm"
        }
    ],
    "Medication": [],
    "Diagnosis": [
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Diagnosis": null
        },
        {
            "Date": "07/30/2021",
            "Diagnosis": null
        }
    ],
    "LabInvestigation": [],
    "LabRequested": [
        {
            "Date": "07/31/2021",
            "LabRequested": {
                "CHEMISTRY": [
                    "Urea"
                ],
                "MARKERS": [
                    "CA-125"
                ],
                "SEROLOGY": [
                    "HBsAg",
                    "HBsAg"
                ],
                "Hematology": [],
                "MICROBIOLOGY": [
                    "Stool_Microscopy"
                ],
                "Anatomical_Pathology": [],
                "IMAGING": [
                    "OBS US"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "_id": "610407db5b0d701034407e97",
    "CardNo": "02",
    "FirstName": "lielina",
    "LastName": "mulugeta",
    "__v": 0,
    "Spot": "Doctor",
    "Dates": [
        "07/30/2021",
        "08/30/2021"
    ]
}]
```

my code

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

function PreviousDetail() {
const location = useLocation();
const CardNo = location.state.CardNo
const url = `http://localhost:4001/PatientProgresss/get/${CardNo}`
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [data1, setData1] = useState([])

var x = 0
useEffect(() => {


 axios.get(url).then(json => setData(json.data[0].Dates))
   .catch(error => {
     console.log('There was an error!', error);
   })
 axios.get(url).then(json => setData1(json.data))
   .catch(error => {
     console.log('There was an error!', error);
   })
}, [])

console.log(data)



return (

 <div className='all-pervious-Detaill'>
   <div className='basic'>
     <div className='p-name'>
       <h3>Paitent name</h3>

     </div>
     <div className='cardNum'>
       <h4>card no</h4> <h4>{CardNo}</h4>
     </div>
   </div>
   {
     data.map((user) =>
     (

       <fieldset className='oneVist'>
         {x = (x + 1)}
         <legend>{data[x - 1]}</legend>
         <div className='vital-sign-vist'>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>BloodPreasure</h5>
             <h5>{data1[0].BloodPressure[x].BloodPressure}</h5>
           </div>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>Temprature</h5>
             <h6 />
           </div>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>Weight</h5>
             <h6></h6>
           </div>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>Hight</h5>
             <h6 />
           </div>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>BMI</h5>
             <h6 />
           </div>
           <div className='one-sing-col'>
             <h5>Pulse</h5>
             <h6 />
           </div>
         </div>
         <hr />
         {/* <div className='detail11'> */}
         < div className='one-sing detail11' >
           <h3>Chief compliant</h3>
           <h5 />
         </div>
         <div className='one-sing'>
           <h3>HPI</h3> <h5 />
         </div>
         <div className='one-sing'>
           <h3>Progress Note</h3> <h5 />
         </div>
         <div className='one-sing'>
           <h3>medication</h3> <h5 />
         </div>
         <div className='one-sing'>
           <h3>Lab invetigations</h3> <h5 />
         </div>
         {/* </div> */}
       </fieldset>


     )


     )
   }



 </div>
)
}

export default PreviousDetail
```

Comment: What is the exact error you were getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'BloodPressure' of undefined

Comment: Can please convert this into codesandbox easy to debug

Comment: You have a line that says `data1[0].BloodPressure`, but I cannot spot where you defined a variable named `data1`. Could this be a typo?

Comment: I found the problem, 5 minutes and I'll post the answer

Comment: data1 is defined before useEffect    const [data1, setData1] = useState([])

Comment: @Lielina add check before mapping 
`data?.map((user) =>........` 
or 
`data.length && data.map((user) =>.....`
so your code will not break

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I figured out what the issue is.  So data1 has the initial value of `[]` because of this line of code `const [data1, setData1] = useState([])`. Now, if you try to get the first element of an empty list, it is going to be `undefined`. This is where the error is coming from.

I think a viable solution would be to check whether the `user` is `undefinded` or not.  You can do that as such:

```
  {
    data.map((user) =>
   (
     {
       user ?? <div> User is not undefined, you can render here the data</div> : <div>Loading... user is still undefinded</div>
     } 
   ) 
 }
```

Comment: i just checked and user is definend

Comment: How can  `user` be defined on the first render? You gave an empty list as data1's value.  The first value in an empty list is `undefined`. So... how does it have a value?